# Use of link rel="preload" for Google Translate

Tags: html, shopify, google-translate, preload

I started using Google Translate for my shopify website im-diamond.com by placing the snippet in the header. Now when I check Chrome Lighthouse report it says it is slowing the site and suggests the use of link rel='preload' . How can I use that to implement the Google Translate's snippet?

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'tr', includedLanguages: 'ar,de,en,ru', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, gaTrack: true, gaId: 'UA-111111-1'}, 'google_translate_element');
  }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The rel=”preload” allows you to prioritize resources that will be needed soon after the page is loaded. As the name describes, the resources will be preloaded and ready to use once they are called. You can find more information about rel=”preload” on this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/link-rel-preload) page.

To use it, place the following line in your HTML header:

```
<link rel="preload" href="scriptName.js" as="script">
```

Where “scriptName.js” is the name of the file containing the Google Translate script you are using. Further in your HTML code where you need to use the preloaded script, use the following line:

```
<script src="scriptName.js"></script>
```